# SQL JOIN COUNT and GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have three tables
 
`1. players(id, first_name, last_name, age, position, team_id)
 2. teams(id, team_name, stadium, wins,  draws,defeats,goal_for,goal_against)
 3. goals_scored(id, player_id, goal_time)`

SQL statement

```
SELECT
    players.first_name, 
    players.last_name,
    teams.name, 
    players.position, 
    players.age, 
    COUNT(*) AS goals 
FROM 
    players 
JOIN goals_scored
    ON players.id = goals_scored.player_id 
JOIN teams 
    ON players.team_id = teams.id 
GROUP BY players.id;
```

teams table
`id team_name stadium    wins draws defeats goal_for goal_against
 1  APF Club  Dasharath   7     2      7        29        25`

players table
`id first_name last_name position age team_id
 4  Dipendra   Shrestha  forward   19    1`

goals_scored table
`id player_id goal_time
 1     4        34
 2     4        57`

I want to group goals on players id so that I can get the count of goals of an individual player.
Like
`first_name last_name team_name position age goals
 Dipendra   Shrestha   APF Club forward   19   2`

How can I do it?

Comment: (1) Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  (2) Tag with the database you are using.  (3) What is the issue with your query?

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the columns you select, except those who are arguments to set functions. I.e. try `GROUP BY players.first_name, 
    players.last_name,
    teams.name, 
    players.position, 
    players.age`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prefer to group on as few as possible columns, especially if multiple tables get involved so that a good index can be applied to handle the group by.

```
WITH GoalsPerPlayer (playerId, nrOfGoals)
AS 
(
    SELECT player_id, count(*)
    FROM goals_scored 
    GROUP BY player_id
)
SELECT p.first_name, p.last_name, t.team_name, p.position, p.age, g.numberOfGoals as goals
FROM GoalsPerPlayer g
INNER JOIN players p ON p.id = g.player_id
INNER JOIN teams t ON t.id = p.team_id
```

**Edit:**

Fixed typo's in query as mentioned by PO in comment below.

```
WITH GoalsPerPlayer (playerId, nrOfGoals)
AS 
(
    SELECT player_id, count(*)
    FROM goals_scored 
    GROUP BY player_id
)
SELECT p.first_name, p.last_name, t.team_name, p.position, p.age, g.nrOfGoals as goals
FROM GoalsPerPlayer g
INNER JOIN players p ON p.id = g.playerId
INNER JOIN teams t ON t.id = p.team_id
```

Comment: Changing g.numberOfGoals to g.nrOfGoals and g.player_id to g.playerId from your solution worked!

Answer (score 0):

Your query basically looks fine.  I would adjust the `GROUP BY` to be more complete:

```
SELECT p.first_name, p.last_name, t.name, p.position, p.age, 
       COUNT(*) AS goals 
FROM players p JOIN
     goals_scored gs
     ON p.id = gs.player_id JOIN
     teams t
     ON p.team_id = t.id 
GROUP BY p.first_name, p.last_name, t.name, p.position, p.age;
```